# how to pass arguments to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, spritebatch

I have a batch file to unzip a file, the path of the zip file and destination folder is hardcoded. I want to unzip different zip files to different folders. I don't want to edit the code all the time, Please some one help on this.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 cd /d %~dp0
 Call :UnZipFile "G:\tett\" "G:\test\test.zip"
 pause
 exit /b
```

This is my batch file, here I am giving the paths of the source and destination. I want to pass the source and destination as arguments to run this batch. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Call :UnZipFile "%~1" "%~2"
```

will call the `:unzipfile` routine passing two parameters as supplied to the batchfile, so from the prompt,

*yourbatchfile* "parameter1" "parameter2"

will accept the two parameters and deliver them to the `:unzipfile` routine.

The parameters only need "quotes" if they contain separators line <kbd>Space</kbd>

`%~1` means "remove the enclosing quotes (if they exist) from the first parameter.

I'll let you guess what `%~2` means...

Comment: Its working fine, but when im running the same script again it prompts "the file is already exists". If it is exists I want to replace, What I need to add

Comment: That would be on the `:unzipfile` subroutine which you haven't shown.

Comment: thanks @Magoo, its working fine, but while extracting I also want to hide the copying window , Is there a way to hide this using our batch script ?